# Dropwizard DAO mock mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, dao, dropwizard

Here is probably a simple question, but I can't get Dao Mocks to work.

```
import com.feetme.backend.jdbi.IRecordDAO;
import com.feetme.backend.representations.Record;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class BasicResourceTest {


private static final IRecordDAO dao = mock(IRecordDAO.class);

private final Record record = getDummyRecord();

@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new BasicResource(dao))
        .build();

private static Record getDummyRecord(){
    Record rec = new Record();
    rec.setId(10);
    return rec;
}


@Before
public void setup() {

    when(dao.findRecordById(eq(10))).thenReturn(record);

    reset(dao);
}

@Test
public void testGetId_Patient() {

    Record r = dao.findRecordById(10);

    assertThat(r).isEqualTo(record);
    assert(r.getId() == 10)
}
```

In this case, both my asserts are never ok.

I also trier to put the reset call in the @After method. Same problem.

My IRecordDAO method normally simply fetches a Record in DB.

I probably missed something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here the DAO interface.

```
@RegisterMapper(RecordMapper.class)
public interface IRecordDAO {

@SqlQuery("sql query ...")
Record findRecordById(@Bind("id") long id);


/**
 * close with no args is used to close the connection
 */
void close();
```

Edit: Actually the problem seems related to the eq() method. When I do something similar with a method of my dao that does not require any parameter, I don't have any problem.

When I replace eq(10) by anyInt() it works fine. I think I'll be fine with it for now but any clue is still welcome.

Finally, replacing eq(10) by 10 works fine. How is eq supposed to be used then ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't `reset(dao)` in your `setup()` method. This is causing the mock dao to forget your previously configured stubbing. See the [Mockito documentation on resetting mocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17).

Comment: Sorry I should have said it before, that's something I tried, but is does not change anything. I put it there because I saw some example where it was there.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: it still shouldn't be there though. It invalidates your stubbing pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

According to `eq`'s java doc

```
public static <T> T eq(T value)
Object argument that is equal to the given value.
```

it's for Objects, while 10 is int which is a primitive type. You could try using `new Integer(10)`, just to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: No it does not make any difference... Thanks.